# How do I set the width of a dropdown-div to be the same as its button

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal top navigation bar with buttons, each of which has a dropdown menu with several links in it, which appear on hover. Everything is working as intended, except for one thing: The dropdown menu is only as wide as its longest link, not as wide as the button that spawns it.

At first I thought it would be an easy fix, just some quick `position: relative;` adjustment or `width:100%`.
But I came across problem with every approach I tried.
This is the code (I'll only inlcude one button, they all function the same):

```css
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #75AE59;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #FF0000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #577649;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   margin-top: 0%;
   visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative; display: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">About us
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">about 1</a>
      <a href="#">about 2</a>
      <a href="#">about 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

   

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

The javascript at the end is there, because I want the topnav to automatically switch to a different format on smaller screens. This is one of the reasons why clunky workarounds didn't work out for me.

If you set dropdown-content div to `position: relative;`, the div actually has the same width as the button, but it screws up the entire topnav. Setting it to `width: 100%` just stretches it to the very edge of the entire page, and inherit doesn't work here. 
Setting their width indivually isn't a solution either, the whole idea of the flexible navbar was to have it look good on any screen size and proportion.

Am I missing something obvious? Or do I need an entire javascript part that can adjust the size of the div to the size of the button?

I would really appreciate any help, I'm sure someone is smart enough to figure this out.